# could i insert a datatime into database as specific timezone?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

as the title,

i want to insert a datetime into a table, for example'

Table'

```
--------------------------
NAME | Type
--------------------------
Id   | Int
Time | Datetime
--------------------------
```

and whatever i insert timezone +9 or timezone -9,
it could saveas timezone +2 in database.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Date time conversion from timezone to timezone in sql server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16872007/date-time-conversion-from-timezone-to-timezone-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 3):

Always use UTC time-zone, and in your display logic do the conversions required each way

Save much confusion later in the project, or when multiple time-zones are required in the future!

See

- [Daylight saving time and time zone best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532729/daylight-saving-time-and-time-zone-best-practices)
- [How to elegantly deal with timezones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7577389/how-to-elegantly-deal-with-timezones)

for further discussions

Comment: thank for your answer, but ... in my project, there is too much data use the sepecial time zone. and, i have to keep new data use the same time zone. so, what i can do is try to convert the utc or whatever to .

Comment: To much data? Like you have more than a billion rows of dates? Even that could be  re-written in an over night job! Fix your problems sooner rather than later. Think of the next  programmer. What mess will they inherit?

Comment: oh...i think so, i hope so.but i cant.