# ASP.Net core MVC FromQuery DateTime in utc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I've got some code similar to:

```
 [HttpGet("SearchStuff")]
    public IActionResult SearchStuff([FromQuery]DateTime from, [FromQuery]DateTime to)
```

I want to make sure I receive in UTC as follows:
If a timezone is specified then convert to UTC
If no timezone is specified then assume UTC and specify as UTC

I tried sending as utc from the client like this (Client works in local time), and it formats as I would expect but unfortunately serverside the datetime was converted to local time of the server. If I use ToString("s") the server receives the correct datetime value but unfortunately with DatetimeKind.Unspecified:

```
protected string Format(DateTime t)
{
    return t.ToUniversalTime().ToString("o");
}
```

Comment: Read this https://stackoverflow.com/a/7583604/3073551

Answer (score 1):

There is also this https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/11584 which provides a workaround it