# Managing Various time zones in MVC by asking user input

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, model-view-controller

How to handle various time zone users in a MVC application if they want to have data operations in their own time zone?

Server hosted in Oregon and working in UTC Time zone.

I need to have user time zone in their registration.

Comment: ask them for their preferred time zone, and then use it? Your question is very vague...what precise difficulty are you facing?

Comment: Save timezone offset as well with UTC time.

Comment: you don't save it with the time, you save it as a per-user preference, and use that when _displaying_ the data. You store all your times in UTC so they are consistent, and then just use the desired offset to change how it gets displayed to the user.

Comment: Yeah  I got it through this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7577389/how-to-elegantly-deal-with-timezones